# ITOP LDAP auth without Anonymous user

Tags: ldap, anonymous

I wanted to integrate LDAP user authentication with Itop. I used the doc https://wiki.openitop.org/doku.php?id=2_1_0:admin:user_authentication_options#configuration_of_ldap_authentication

However, anonymous user authentication is disabled in our active directory setup. Administrator user details can't be mentioned in config file due to security reasons. Is there any other way to authenticate the AD users to Itop with PHP?
Appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

You should request an openitop service account from your AD administrator.  Then, adjust file permissions so that only openitop service and administrators are allowed to read the configuration files containing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I configured mod_auth_ntlm_winbind. Configure the same and it will help to fetch REMOTE_USER parameter and this can be passed to ITOP configuration file. Create users with "External Authentication" from ITOP and this will give SSO logins

Complete steps, refer: https://hemakhema.blogspot.ae/2017/07/enable-sso-login-in-linux.html